# Use cookiecutter-django with Celery 4.x

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, celery, cookiecutter-django

I use cookiecutter-django with celery==3.1.25. 
Now I need use tasks scheduler, and my opinion, best way for this - it's celery beat.

But [here](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat/issues/3#issuecomment-249666479) I found information that celery-beat works with Celery version 4.x

[Here](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/pull/1249) I saw the information that pyup-bot on July 24 offered to update Celery to version 4.1.0, but this issue is still open.

Prompt, how to be in my situation? I like cookiecutter-django and I'm using it now in my project, but also, I really need a task scheduler.

I have not yet tried to replace the version of Celery, but I think that this will lead to a number of mistakes, otherwise it would have been done before me.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use beat with celery 3.X.

Just add a section in your settings:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    # Executes every Monday at midnight
    'do-task-every-monday': {
        'task': 'path-to-your-task',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=0, minute=0, day_of_week=1),
        'args': (),
    },
}
```

As for Celery 4.x support on cookiecutter-django, see the on-going discussion at this [PR](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/pull/1249).